# Layout Android com bordar coloridas

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá,

Alguém sabe como faço bordas arredondadas e coloridas em uma tela android(layout).
Acredito que deva existir algum item configurável no XML porém não sei qual e nem tenho certeza se é possível.
A ideia é que fique como uma moldura mesmo, só que com os cantos arredondados.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você terá que criar um *drawable* com cantos arredondados e defini-lo como background do seu *layout* ou em qualquer *view* que desejar.

Segue um exemplo com bordas verdes:

**drawable/rounded.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#79FF4D" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar um `Shape` no formato de retangulo na pasta `drawable` e definilo como `background` da sua `view`:

**drawable/borda_azul.xml**

```
<shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" >

   // A cor do background
   <solid android:color="#FF0099FF" />

   // Borda (tamanho e cor)
   <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#d4d4d4" />

   // Arredondamento das bordas
   <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
       android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
       android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

E defina como background de algum elemento assim:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/borda_azul">

      ...Seus componentes (Botões, etc)

</LinearLayout>
```